# How to utilize a variable from a different class in a unit testing in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, class, methods

I want to utilize the variable `numberOwned` from a different class in my test file in Scala. How do I do that?

Here is what I attempted.

TestEquipment.scala:

```
package tests
import clicker.equipment._
import org.scalatest._

class TestEquipment extends FunSuite {
    numberOwned = 0
        test("first test"){
    }
}
```

Equipment.scala

```
package clicker.equipment

abstract class Equipment{

var numberOwned = 0
var name: String = ""

def goldPerSecond(): Double

}
```

File Directory

```
src
 |_clicker
 |     |_ equipment
 |           |_Equipment.scala
 |_ tests
      |_ TestEquipment.scala
```

Answer (score 0):

As your abstract class doesn't have any state you can convert it to Trait (Interface) and in Scala you can define interfaces with methods as in below

```
trait Equipment{

  var numberOwned = 0
  var name: String = ""

  def goldPerSecond(): Double = {
      numberOwned
  }
}

 class TestEquipment extends FunSuite with Equipment {
    this.numberOwned = 0
        test("first test"){
    }
}
```

You can extend your TestEquipment with FunSuite and implement the interface Equipment.

As mentioned in comments you cannot inherit from FunSuite and BaseClass at the same time.

Comment: this answer came in Low Quality posts in SO since its code only answer.... Could you add any commentary to your answer? Explain your logic, and give a little commentary on what your code is intended to do. This will help the OP, but it will also serve as commentary for future users

Comment: Can you use an abstract class instead of a trait class?

Comment: @Anonymous Then you can't use `FunSuite` (use `FunSuiteLike` instead).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't depend on whether it's in a test: you need an instance of `Equipment`.

```
class TestEquipment extends FunSuite {
    val equipment: Equipment = ...    
    equipment.numberOwned = 0

    test("first test"){ ... }
}
```

In Scala, you can do `import equipment._` and refer to `numberOwned` directly, but that doesn't change the meaning.

This instance can be `this`, as in skjagini's answer, but it doesn't make much sense semantically: *is* your test suite a kind of equipment?